# WebContent Management 2DAY VS. CQ5?

Tags: aem

Can somebody explain the deffirent between `WebContent Management 2DAY(Adobe  DayCQ4)` and `CQ5` ?

Answer (score 0):

CQ 4 is just an earlier version. CQ was initially develeoped by [Day Software AG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_Software) which was bought by Adobe a few years ago. The latest version is no longer called CQ but AEM though the continued with the numbering so it is AEM 6.
Though the basic concepts of CQ were introduced with CQ 4, CQ 5 is quite different. As CQ 4 is a legacy product, you don't find much information anymore.